# How to add a round border on a mp4 video on squarespace

Tags: css, squarespace, border-radius

I'm trying to add a border radius in a square space video and it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

I am trying to put a round border on the video and tried this code below:

```
#block-df45bbc957de1bd8c905.video-block .video-player{
 padding-bottom:120%;
 border-radius: 10px;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the html or try to reproduce a small demo? Some guidelines to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that the `border-radius` property takes precedence over any incompatible CSS rules, you can try adding the`!important` keyword after it as shown below:

```
#block-df45bbc957de1bd8c905.video-block .video-player{
  padding-bottom: 120%;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```